# Why do I need to test Redux implementations while I can just test the DOM using a testing library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I can't understand the full process of testing. I am using a testing library and I feel comfortable with testing just texts, labels and I feel I don't need to test any implementation in React or [Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library)), and this is what I read in the React testing library documentation, as [Enzyme](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme) forced people always to test React implementations.

Now if all texts, labels and displayed values are right in my tests, this means that everything should be OK, but unfortunately when I am using Redux, I am always forced to test **Redux** implementations (mocking the store, mocking reducers, etc.) and **async behaviors** like fetching data and so on.

Why do I need and am forced to test **Redux** implementations as long as I can just test displayed values and passed tests will always indicate that **Redux** implementations work correctly in my project?

Comment: When you mock a redux provider for your UI you ***aren't*** testing any redux implementation, you are simply providing the data and hooks the UI under test needs. Anything mocked is effectively ***not*** being tested. This is the biggest reason I still prefer to decouple my presentation UI components from any data sources, it allows me to simply mock the would-be props in complete isolation of any underlying datasource. You will still want to test your reducers, selectors, and any async action handlers separately.

Comment: but i still need to mock store and reducers,actions! @DrewReese

Comment: How can you decouple it, can you give me some hints please? @DrewReese

Comment: Right, because you are testing the UI does correct things with the props it receives. This is what Unit Testing is, testing each "unit" of code decoupled and separate from other "units". As I mentioned, you should also unit test your app state logic as well so you can confirm it behaves as you expect it to. Mocking is an example of a way to decouple UI from *actual* implementation of data layer.

Comment: @DrewReese, this article what confused me really about testing, they encourage testing just displayed values instead of any thing else, i hope i have understood it wrongly

https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/migrate-from-enzyme

Comment: Yes, that is because RTL is a UI testing framework. The UI, what a user sees, is just one aspect or dimension of your application. In an app I've been involved with at my company I would say easily 70-80% of our unit test code tests code a user *never* sees. In fact, most of our UI tests are simpler render tests, i.e. they simply render the props passed to them without crashing.

Comment: @DrewReese they are against testing state, and say that some of enzyme developers works now on testing library because they are convinced that that the way of testing using enzyme wasn't right! :)

Comment: RTL isn't against testing *component* state, it is against direct manipulation of state and props as a form of testing simply because that isn't at all how a user interacts with the UI components, hence why RTL uses the component's API, i.e. the props and elements ***in*** the UI to interact with the component. Sorry, this is turning into a discussion. Kent Dodds has many articles about react component testing.

Comment: @CodeEagle "because they are convinced that that the way of testing using enzyme wasn't right!" - sounds about right. The JavaScript developer ecosystem is very fast-moving and full of rivalry and competition - which can be a good thing, but the ease at which an inexperienced team or person can rediscover/reinvent/reimplement something that the rest of the industry learned decades ago and launch it as some new framework or library and end-up getting millions of downloads on npm is... concerning. (see: [the `leftPad` debacle](https://www.theregister.com/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/), ugh).

Comment: @Dai A day that will live in infamy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't understand the full process of testing

That's understandable. Testing and software quality assurance is a huge professional field (there's more to it than video game playtesting!)

> I am using a testing library and I feel comfortable with testing just texts, labels and I feel I don't need to test any implementation in React or Redux

This is the wrong attitude to have. What you're describing is a very *non-rigorous*, slapdash, haphazard - and most importantly: shallow kind of testing.

Just because data on the user's computer screen *appears* correct, it doesn't mean it actually is. How do you know you aren't actually interacting with a mocked UI or that the backend database actually contains the new data? Or that there weren't any negative side effects (such as the system *deleting everything else* - and yes, that happened to me once...).

By analogy, you're saying you'd be happy to fly in an airplane that was tested only by ensuring that moving [the control yoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoke_(aeronautics)) resulted in the [on-screen airplane icon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_indicator) moving in the right direction - even if the plane is still firmly on the ground. I would not want to fly on that plane.

> Now if all texts, labels, displayed values all are true in my tests, this means that everything should be OK

No, it doesn't. See above.

> but unfortunately when I am using Redux, I always forced to test Redux implementations (mocking the store, mocking reducers, etc.) and async behaviors like fetching data and so on.

Yes. You're being forced to *the right thing*. It's called [the Pit of Success](https://blog.codinghorror.com/falling-into-the-pit-of-success/). Don't fight it. It's for the best. These libraries, platforms and frameworks are designed by people with more experience in software design than both of us, so if they tell us to do something we should do what they say - if we disagree we need to formalize our objections and duke it out in GitHub issues with *academic rigour*, not Stack Overflow posts arguing that something's unnecessary because you just *don't feel like it*. With apologies for being blunt, but I hope you never work in a safety-critical industry or sector until your attitude changes because I never want to see another [Therac-25 incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25) - which was directly caused by people sharing your attitude towards software testing.

> Why do I need and am forced to test Redux implementations as long as I can just test displayed values and passed tests will always indicate that Redux implementations work correctly in my project?

Because what you're describing does not provide for anywhere close to [full code-coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage).

---

Here's a bunch of assorted things to consider:

- Software testing (and systems testing in general, in any field) can generally be lumped into these categories:

  - Unit testing: testing a single "unit" of your code in isolation from everything else.

    - (Side-note: many people are currently abusing unit-testing frameworks like [xUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit) and [MSTest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework) to implement what are actually *integration tests*, so many people don't understand the real difference between *integration* and unit tests, which is depressing...). A "unit" would be something like a **single** `class` or `function`, not an entire GUI application.
    - Your current testing strategy is not a unit test because you aren't testing anything in isolation: you have to fire-up the entire application, including the React/Redux pipeline, web-server *and* an extremely complicated, multi-billion-dollar GUI web-browser program application.
    - Generally speaking: "if you need concrete dependencies (instead of fakes or mocks) to test something, it isn't a unit-test, it's an integration-test".
  - Integration testing: testing multiple components that interact with each other.

    - This is a rather abstract definition - but it can mean things like testing an application's business logic code when it's coupled to (a copy!) of your production database. This could also include testing a business-layer when there's a GUI attached to it, but GUI testing is not easily automated - so many, but not all, people would not consider what you're doing as a unit-test, especially as what you've described implies that your tests aren't testing for side-effects or verifying other changes of state elsewhere in the system (such as the database or a backend web-service).
  - There are other types of tests besides *unit* and *integration* - but those two are the main types of *fully automated tests* that every application should have - and every application should have good code-coverage from unit and integration tests especially. Do note that code-coverage does not imply exhaustiveness, and achieving 100% code-coverage is often a waste of time if that code includes *trivial implementations* like boilerplate code, or parameter validation code, or code generated by a tool that itself is very-well tested.

    - Generally speaking: if a piece of code "is complicated" or changes regularly, it should have "good" (75%+? 80%? 90%?) code-coverage.
- Because testing software via GUIs is very difficult (and brittle: as GUIs are probably the part that experiences major changes the most in any user-facing software system) it's actually often not subject to automated testing anywhere near as much as it should - which is why it's important to ensure good coverage of non-GUI parts with automated testing which also reduces the amount of manual GUI testing that needs doing.
- Finally, a big thing to consider with the Redux pattern in particular is that Redux is not specific to GUI applications. Theoretically you should be able to take a Redux application and copy and paste it into a server-side Node.js JavaScript application and hook it up to a virtual DOM and hey-presto, your application no longer requires client-side JavaScript to work! It also means you can get great code-coverage of your application just by using a special virtual DOM that's intended for testing rather than a real browser DOM - but your current approach will not work with this because you're talking about only verifying changes to a real browser DOM, not a virtual DOM.

Comment: this is just like cold water bath in a cold day, thank you

Comment: @CodeEagle I'm unfamiliar with that idiom - I don't know how I should be interpreting it.